# Validate messages are sent in a specific language

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

I have a checklist field with languages and they are bound to custom fields from collection field which contains messages. That means that in the app the user can fill several message fields with different languages.

My business requirement is to validate if the user has sent  AT LEAST ONE MESSAGE IN ENGLISH ('`EN`' from the checklist) language. Is there a possibility in Symfony to validate that?

Also, the next requirement is to prevent the user from sending messages in same languages. Is there any requirement condition or something like that?

I'll be glad for any answers or code.

This is my private field (array type):

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
private $texts = array();
```

The example structure of this array could be something like this:

```
$texts = [
[0] => {'lang' => 'EN', 'title' => 'Title1', 'text' => 'Text1'}, 
[1] => {'lang' => 'FR', 'title' => 'Title1', 'text' => 'Text1'}]
```

I've tried validating by using Collection constraint but It does't worked because it need string only.

I want to know if there is any solution to check this kind of array field on entity.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You could create [your own validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html). Test the linked documentation and then, if you don't find a solution, you can create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your problem. It's hard to answer to your question (too broad)

Comment: So 1 message must be in EN, but only one message per language including EN?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing your current setup, but you need to simply store which language(s) they have sent in and check them all. ie each language they choose in an array and check if dupe exists, then check if "EN" exists. Handle appropriately. How you handle or even approach this can be done in many ways in Symfony, so is beyond the scope of a question here really (without lots more info about what you use, ie twig, etc etc)